# How to keep the toolbar fixed at the top when AppBar collapses/expands?

Tags: android, material-design, android-appbarlayout

### Overview

I am trying to implement one of the [Scrolling Techniques](https://www.google.co.in/design/spec/patterns/scrolling-techniques.html#scrolling-techniques-scrolling), *Flexible space with overlapping content*, described in Material Design.

> **Flexible space with overlapping content**
>
> Content can overlap the app bar.
>
> Behavior:
>
> The app bar’s starting position should be located behind the content.
> Upon upward scroll, the app bar should scroll faster than the content,
> until the content no longer overlaps it. Once anchored in place, the
> app bar lifts up to allow content to scroll underneath.
>
> https://www.google.co.in/design/spec/patterns/scrolling-techniques.html#scrolling-techniques-scrolling

---

### Problem

However, the problem is,
the title in my AppBar scrolls down when expanded and hides below the overlapping content.

Here, my toolbar is hidden below the overlapping CardView.
[image: When appbar expanded]

When the appbar is collapsed, the toolbar and hence the Title slides up from below.
[image: When collapsed]

### Code

Here's my Code:

activity-main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    ...
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            ...
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        ...
```

I have also added these in my MainActivity's onCreate function

```
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("App Name");
```

---

I want the toolbar(with the tile and the other contents, which I will add later) to stay at the top irrespective of the appbar being expanded or collapsed.

I have read the documentations, gone through many posts and tutorials, watched a lot of videos but failed to find a working solution or any related solutions at all.

If anyone has some idea on how to fix this, please suggest. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I was looking for a solution myself when I found the answer in the comments on a similar issue report.

Basically you call `setTitleEnabled()` on your `CollapsingToolbarLayout` like this:

```
CollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(false);
```

You can do this in xml as well, by adding this to your `CollapsingToolbarLayout`:

```
app:titleEnabled="false"
```

By setting it to `false`, you'll get the desired behaviour. The title stays fixed to the top of the screen.

The `Toolbar` itself was actually already at the top, but this makes the title stay there as well, instead of translating between the bottom of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and the `Toolbar`.

Comment: Thanks, will try soon as I get my laptop fixed.

Comment: I tried this, and with `titleEnabled=false` the title stays at the top, but one strange thing with that is that now the title string is always the activity label. Calling `setTitle` on either the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` or the `Toolbar` itself has no effect. Don't know if that's expected.

Answer (score 5):

I have acheived this by adding below code inside `Toolbar` tag.

```
app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case I needed to add `app:titleEnabled="false"` to the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` **AND** `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` to the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

Now the toolbar stays pinned to the top of the screen, irrespective of whether the user scrolls up or down.

Answer (score 2):

**To keep title at top**, simple put this attribute to your `CollapsingToolbarLayout`:

```
app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
```

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me.I think the many different solutions are because of the many ways you can implement. For me this worked because I have a androidx Toolbar inside my CollapsingToolbar layout, and I'm setting the text via the CollapsingToolbar (not directly to the Toolbar). These things need to be specified more when people post solutions.