# How to Pin toolbar in a coordinator layout using collapsing toolbar?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to make the toolbar appear in this layout always visible instead of it appearing only when it is scrolled out completely. I have an image inside collapsing toolbar that needs to get hidden when scrolled out fully.

This is what I tried.. Any opinion on how to achieve it?

```
        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".activities.Event_details">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/topLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
        android:layout_gravity="top" >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/page_innerheader_titletxt"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/save_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/save"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorYellow"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize16"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/toolbarButton"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/toolbarButton"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/done"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:background="@drawable/rect_yellow"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

           </RelativeLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/topLayout"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/party"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

<!--

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/page_innerheader_titletxt"
                        android:text="@string/app_name"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/save_toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/save"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorYellow"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize16"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/toolbarButton"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/toolbarButton"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:text="@string/done"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:background="@drawable/rect_yellow"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
-->


            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <include layout="@layout/content_main_eventdetails" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

P.S: I also tried using the toolbar inside the collapsing toolbar but I can make only the title and button visible but I want the whole toolbar to have a `colorPrimary` background.

I tried these links [collapsing toolbar fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32064046/how-to-keep-the-toolbar-fixed-at-the-top-when-appbar-collapses-expands) and this [AppBar layout behaviour](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/appbarlayout-scroll-behavior-with-layout-scrollflags-2eec41b4366b) and some from the other SO threads. But nothing seems to solve my problem.

Comment: can you add screenshot ? what you need or what's happening?

Comment: Usually in collapsing toolbar with an image when you scroll, the image collapses to a toolbar(ref:https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/appbarlayout-scroll-behavior-with-layout-scrollflags-2eec41b4366b). 

But what I want to achieve is that the toolbar should always be fixed even before collapsing and only the image should be collapsed when scrolled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivBack"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="Title"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivBack"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivBack"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivBack" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

                // Your Image View


            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            // RecyclerView if required
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="128dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In this code snippet, I have created a `Toolbar` and `CoordinatorLayout` which are inside the `ConstraintLayout`

`Toolbar` contains the `ConstraintLayout` which set the back button and title.

`CoordinatorLayout` has `AppBarLayout` which has `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in which you can set you `ImageView`.

Comment: Hello @sanjeev. Did you try the above solution?

Comment: Ok great. Let me know in case of any query

Comment: Great Solution. Works as expected! Thanks Man.. :)

Comment: quick question what if I have to place a view that overlaps(that stays over both the toolbar and coordinator)??

Comment: @sanjeev in that case what you can do is create another `layout` inside parent `ConstraintLayout ` and place it above the toolbar layout.
And also you might have to give `elevation` to that view to make it above the other views(i.e. Toolbar and Coordinator)